# How to get Standard and Custom Object List in Apex class

Tags: apex, standard-objects, schema

I am trying to get all Standard and Custom Objects name from Schema class in apex class. I need to remove all shared objects from the list.

Comment: I have used Schema.getDescribe() with few common "is" methods like isqueryable, isupdatable. Removed many but still few of them are coming for which I don't have access or isn't in use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is updated code that will give list of all objects excluding Share, history , Tag & feed. You can add extra condition to filter out other unnecessary sObjects.

```
List<string> SObjectList = new List<string>();

for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
   String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
   // Exclude all the unwanted Sobjects e.g. History, Share etc..

 if((!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag')&&
    !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed')) || 
     name.toLowerCase().right(3) ==  '__c'){      
      SobjectList.add(name);
      System.debug( 'Name : ' + name);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't working. Template, Rule, Role everything is coming.

Comment: Thats why i said "You can add extra condition to filter out other unnecessary sObjects"

Comment: I m looking for those extra conditions only ;) . Excluding name manually wouldn't help.

Comment: Check qs' comment for the things i have tried.

Comment: Why cant you write those extra conditions?

Comment: Dont expect community to write end to end code for you.  We can give you clues and directions but can not write complete solution for you .

Comment: I am not expecting to get whole code but the problem is I cannot exactly write the way you have done in answer.

Comment: If I had a custom object called Stag_Party__c  - I wouldn't get it back in this list either would I? Because it contains 'tag'..

Comment: @SimonLawrence Good point, to handle that we can add OR condition something like this || 
         name.toLowerCase.right(3) ==  '__c'

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way, it works fine. Please test it.

```
global static List<String> getAllCustomSObjects()
{
    List<String> sObjectList = new List<String>();
    for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values())
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResultObj = objTyp.getDescribe();
        if(describeSObjectResultObj.isCustom())
        {
            String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
            // Exclude all the unwanted Sobjects e.g. History, Share etc..
            if(!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag')&&
             !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed'))
            {
                SobjectList.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('SObjectList****' + SObjectList);
    return sObjectList;
}
```

Comment: For standard object, rule, role are also standard object

Comment: Yeah I get that. Already added couple of more conditions on describeSObjectResultObj . Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there's not a great way to exclude all objects like share, tag, etc. from the Schema.getGlobalDescribe() results apart from using the String class .contains() method as shown above. This still leaves a lot of unwanted objects in the list though, as not all of them have a set naming convention that can be detected and filtered.

Although not dynamic, depending on your use case you may try something like the following:

```
    private Set<String> desiredStandardObjects = new Set<String>{'Account','User',...};

    List<String> objectList = new List<String>();
    for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult obj = objTyp.getDescribe();
        if((obj.isCustom() && !obj.getName.contains('ChangeEvent')) || desiredStandardObjects.contains(obj.getName()){
                objectList.add(name);
            
        }
    }
```

This way you filter out most of the unwanted objects and keep all the custom objects and wanted standard objects.

There are still some "system" objects that are technically custom objects. For example every custom object has a ChangeEvent object that is autogenerated by Salesforce. You can filter out by the String 'ChangeEvent' in the API name to help with that.